# Как реализовать удаление записи при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: php

Есть цикл в которым выводятся посты:

```
<div class="textpost" id="textpost">
    <?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
        <div class="post" ><b><?php echo $post['title'] ?></b></div>
        <div class="post" ><i><?php echo $post['description'] ?></i></div>
        <div class="post" ><?php echo $post['texting'] ?></div><br>
        <input type="submit" value="del">
    <?php endforeach; ?>    
</div>
```

И метод который удаляет записи из формы:

```
public function delete($id) {
    $dbh = Db::getConnect();
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = '$id'");
    $sth->execute();
}
```

Подскажите как можно реализовать такую вещь, что бы при нажатии на кнопку срабатывала функция delete

Comment: например вот статья http://dnzl.ru/view_post.php?id=272 и если зайти в гугл немного поискать то таких статтей можно найти сотни

Answer (score 0):

```
input type="submit" name="delete[тут пишите значение сколько хотите удалить]" value="Удалить" стрелочки вначале и в конце не забудьте < >
```

И в контроллере ловите:

```
$id = key($_POST['delete']);
```

Если не ошибаюсь, то должно быть так